# Page break issues after Report Viewer upgrade from 9.0 to 11.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer, rdlc, page-break

After upgrading from MS Report Viewer 9.0 (VS 2008) to 11.0 (VS 2013), I've discovered that one of my reports is not rendering the same. Previously I would see two of my detail groups per page, but now only one. Here are screen shots of before and after:

Before upgrade:
[before upgrade http://www.libersys.net/images/benchsheet_old.png](http://www.libersys.net/images/benchsheet_old.png)

After upgrade:
[after upgrade http://www.libersys.net/images/benchsheet_new.png](http://www.libersys.net/images/benchsheet_new.png)

I'm more of a Crystal Reports guy so I still haven't gotten my head around all of the nuances of MS RDLCs. Just looking for clues on how to make render the same way it did before the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to contact MS support on this issue. They basically said that since the report engine had been completely rewritten they could not guarantee that any given report would render the same after conversion from VS2008 to VS2013 report format. They ended up having to make modifications to the report template in order to ensure that my two detail groups would not be split by page breaks.